# Set heartbeatintervalseconds using spring xml

Tags: spring, cassandra, spring-data, datastax-java-driver, spring-data-cassandra

I am using spring-data-Cassandra v1.3.2 in my project.
Is it possible to set heartbeatintervalseconds using spring configuration XML file.

Getting 4 lines of hearbeat DEBUG logs every 30 seconds in my application logs and i am not sure how to avoid them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.

After reviewing the SD Cassandra [CassandraCqlClusterParser](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-cassandra/blob/master/spring-cql/src/main/java/org/springframework/cassandra/config/xml/CassandraCqlClusterParser.java) class, it is apparent that you can [specify both "local" and "remote" connection pooling options](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-cassandra/blob/master/spring-cql/src/main/java/org/springframework/cassandra/config/xml/CassandraCqlClusterParser.java#L145-L148), however, [neither handler handles](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-cassandra/blob/master/spring-cql/src/main/java/org/springframework/cassandra/config/xml/CassandraCqlClusterParser.java#L243-L264) all the Cassandra Java driver "[pooling options](http://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-java-driver-api/com/datastax/driver/core/PoolingOptions.html)" appropriately (such as `heartbeatIntervalSeconds`).

It appears several other options are missing as well: `idleTimeoutSeconds`, `initializationExecutor`, `poolTimeoutMillis`, and `protocolVersion`.

Equally unfortunate is it appears the SD Cassandra [PoolOptionsFactoryBean](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/1.4.1.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/cassandra/config/PoolingOptionsFactoryBean.html) does not support these "[pooling options](http://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-java-driver-api/com/datastax/driver/core/PoolingOptions.html)" either.

However, not all is lost.

While your SD Cassandra application may resolve it's configuration primarily from XML, it does not preclude you from using a combination of Java config and XML.

For instance, you could use a *Spring* Java config class to configure your cluster and express your `PoolingOptions` in Java config...

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource("/class/path/to/cassandra/config.xml")
class CassandraConfig {

  @Bean
  PoolingOptions poolingOptions() {
    PoolingOptions poolingOptions = new PoolingOptions();

    poolingOptions.setHeartbeatIntervalSeconds(30);
    poolingOptions.setIdleTimeoutSeconds(300);
    poolingOptions.setMaxConnectionsPerHost(50);
    poolingOptions.set...

    return poolingOptions;
  }

  @Bean
  CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster() {
    CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster = new CassandraClusterFactoryBean()

    cluster.setContactPoints("..");
    cluster.setPort(1234);
    cluster.setPoolingOptions(poolingOptions());
    cluster.set...

    return cluster;
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

As an FYI, you may want to upgrade to the "current" [Spring Data Cassandra](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-cassandra/) version, `1.4.1.RELEASE`.

Comment: See DATACASS-298 (https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACASS-298) for more details and progress concerning this issue.

Comment: PR submitted (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-cassandra/pull/66) with the fix which will be available in `1.5 M1 (Ingalls)`.

Comment: Thanks for update.For time being i have disabled heartbeat logs via log4j.Earlier i was planning to increase the interval.

Comment: Good to know. As an FYI the PR has been merged (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-cassandra/commit/3d9835d99aaa8e06bf10f5f276fc96713f45ba22) and will be available in SDC 1.5 M1 (Ingalls).  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, but the answer is no. It's not possible to configure the heartbeat interval using XML configuration. Only the following local/remote properties can be configured in `PoolingOptions`:

- `min-simultaneous-requests`
- `max-simultaneous-requests`
- `core-connections`
- `max-connections`

If you switch to Java-based configuration, then you're able to configure `PoolingOptions` by extending `AbstractClusterConfiguration`:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig extends AbstractClusterConfiguration {

    @Override
    protected PoolingOptions getPoolingOptions() {

        PoolingOptions poolingOptions = new PoolingOptions();
        poolingOptions.setHeartbeatIntervalSeconds(10);
        return poolingOptions
    }
}
```